# How to embed/use Existing Java Web Project in to my Android Application?

Tags: java, android, jsp, servlets, android-webview

I am not that expert in Android app development. I'm confused at one point.

I have a Java web project developed using Jsp,Servlets etc. Now I want to create an Android app which would be the same in functionality/overall of existing web project.

What are best approaches to develop such kind of Android app?

Should I start creating from scratch or is it possible to embed most of the part to create Android app?

Or WebView of Android will work for all files of web project?

Comment: Well, this is really a question for the product owners. If you build api your android app can access directly this will take longer. If you use a webview to display the pages, you _may_ still have to modify the pages for the smaller screens.

Comment: @Ali Yes I've restfull API of project. Could you elaborate how to access API from Android app. Thanks.

Comment: Just do an `HTTPGet` to access data. Look at this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html).

Comment: @ali i have standalone desktop application as well. But this tutorial only showing how to access HTTP and not exactly the solution to my question. :/